# Partitions of unity exercise: Showing existence of smooth function zero on closed subset.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry, solution-verification, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. Let $B \subset M$ be closed and suppose $\delta:M \to \Bbb{R}^+$ be continuous.

(a) Using partitions of unity, prove there exists a smooth function $\tilde{\delta}: M \to \Bbb{R}^+$ such that $\tilde{\delta}(x) \in (0,\delta(x))$ for all $x \in M$.

(b) Prove there exists a continuous function $\psi: M \to \Bbb{R}$ that is smooth and positive on $M \setminus B$, identically equal to zero on $B$, and satisfies $\psi(x) < \delta(x)$ everywhere on $M$.

For part one I have

(a) As $M$ is a smooth manifold, if $\mathbf{X}=\{X_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ is any arbitrary open covering of $M$, then by Theorem 2.23 of Lee, there exists a smooth partition of unity subordinate to $\mathbf{X}$. (i.e., a family of cont functions between and includiong $0$ and $1$, supports contains in each open set, fam of supports is locally finite, the sum of functions is 1 for every $x \in M$)
Furthermore, by our assumption suppose
$\delta: M \to \Bbb{R}^+$
is a continuous mapping. For each $p \in M$, let $U_p \subset M$ be open and choose $\epsilon_p >0$ such that
$$\epsilon_p < \inf \delta(U_p).$$
Since $M$ is paracompact, there exists an open covering $\{W_i\}_{i \in I}$ such that for each $p \in M$ we can choose $i \in I$ such that $W_i \subset U_p$. then put $\delta_i:=\epsilon_p$, then on $W_i$ we have $\delta_i<\inf \delta(W_i)$. Thus putting
$$\tilde{\delta}(x):=\sum \delta_i \psi_i(x)$$
works and we have $\tilde{\delta}(x) \in (0,\delta(x))$ as needed. Furthermore, $\tilde{\delta}$ is continuous as it is a sum of continuous functions with scalars.

For part (b) Do I use part (a) as I already have a continuous delta, its also smooth as the $\psi_i$ are all smooth and its less than $\delta(x)$ on $M$ all that is left to show is its zero on $B$? So do I tweak my $\tilde{\delta}$?? also, is my part (a) correct? For (b) I saw a hint where if $f: M \setminus B \to \Bbb{R}$ then consider $g(x)=\frac{1}{1+f}$ but I thought Id be using the $\tilde{\delta}$ I found in (a). And where do I get that the function is $0$ on $B$ with $g(x)$. ANY HINTS OR TIPS APPRECIATED!!

Comment: I might be missing something obvious, but how do you know that $0<\inf_{U_p} \delta$?

Comment: $\delta$ is positive valued. @Al.G.

Comment: @Al.G. so the infimum would need to be positive or wait it could be $0$, is that what you meant???

Comment: I recommend you choose a more informative title

Comment: @FShrike hows it now

Comment: Sure. Note that positive sets can have $\inf=0$

Comment: If $U_p$ is open and $\delta$ is positive, you cannot know for sure if $0<\inf_{U_p}\delta$. As FShrike said, it's the same as saying that $U\subset\mathbb R_+$ implies $\inf U>0$ - it's not true in general. For example, take $\delta(x)=x$ (the identity), $U_p=M=(0,1)\subset \mathbb R$. Then $\delta(x) > 0$ for all $x\in U_p$ but $\inf \delta = 0$.